# The error term in a result of Landau

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The standard asymptotic for the harmonic sum has a form such as

A) $$\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{n}=\log x +\gamma+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{12x^2}+\frac{\alpha}{65x^4},$$
where $\alpha \in (0,1)$, see Probabilistic Number Theory, Tanenbaum, Theorem 0.8.

There are two published results based on the formula

B) $$\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{n}=\log x +\gamma+\frac{\{x\}-1/2}{x}+O\left (\frac{1}{x^2} \right ),$$
where $\{x\}=x-[x]$ is the fractional part, see "On an error  term of Landau II", Sidaramachandrarao, Rocky Mount. Math journal, Vol. 15, No. 2, 1985, page 583, equation (2.9).

Question 1. Is formula B correct?

Question 2. Does Landau result remains as the best error term for the sum $\sum_{n \leq x}1/\varphi(n)$?

Comment: It's Tenenbaum (Gérald) who by the way is not only a number theorist but also a writer.

Comment: For Question 1 - do not both A and also the well known [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation)$$H_n\sim \ln{n}+\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k n^{k}}=\ln{n}+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+\frac{1}{120n^4}-\cdots$$imply B easily?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: It surely does, but there is the subtlety that the OP's first display is valid for integer $x\geq 1$, while the second display is valid for all real $x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 10):

Please exercise more care when quoting a result. The first result is Theorem 0.5 from Tenenbaum: Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory. The correct form of this result is
$$\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{n}=\log x +\gamma+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{12x^2}+\frac{\alpha}{\color{red}{60}x^4},$$
where $\alpha\in(0,1)$, and **it is valid for positive integers $x$ only**.
The second result holds (for arbitrary real $x\geq 1$) in the form
$$\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{n}=\log x +\gamma\color{red}-\frac{\{x\}-1/2}{x}+O\left (\frac{1}{x^2} \right ),$$
and it can be proved easily with Euler-Maclaurin summation (specifically by two integration by parts).

The quoted article (which is available freely [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250127232)) mentions an earlier paper by the same author (Indian J. Pure Appl. Math. 13 (1982), 882-885) which improves Landau's error term $O(\log x/x)$ to $O((\log x)^{2/3}/x)$. Based on the MathSciNet quotations of these two papers, in particular a 2014 paper by Sankaranarayanan and Singh, this appears to be the best known error term at the moment.